# Do orbitals of electrons line up in external magnetic field?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, orbitals

If a current carrying loop is in external magnetic field it feels the force and moves to its equillibrium position. Similarly, in quantum level will electrons revolve nucleus in a lined up manner for externalmagnetic field ?(Thinking revolving as not an orbit but its its direction of revolving makes it line up) Can we able to modify distribution of electrons?

Answer (score 0):

Most of the effect is indirect, via spin-orbit coupling. That is for ordinary fields. With the kind of field that we humans are able to create we cannot significantly modify the distribution of electrons by a direct effect on the orbits.

For extreme fields (like at the surface of neutron stars) atomic physics gets complicated.